# Detect long touch in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a node in a SKScene that I am moving as per the users touch. Basically, this character should also be trying to follow the users finger (Assuming the finger is on the screen). I currently have it implemented as so, which works fine:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    player.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(touch.locationInNode(self), duration: 1))
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    player.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(touch.locationInNode(self), duration: 1))
}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
    player.removeAllActions()
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    player.removeAllActions()
}
```

However, the problem is that if a user holds his/her finger on the phone. The touchesBegan is only called once, and that's when the tap starts, not when it is held. I want the player character to constantly be trying to reach the finger.

I am centering the camera on the node, so the only time the node should be touching the finger is if the user puts his finger on/in the node (I.e the same position as the node). Because of this, after I run the SKAction to move the node the touch is invalid since it is at the old position.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two instance variables to your SKScene, `BOOL fingerIsTouching` and `CGPoint touchLocation`.

Inside `-touchesBegan:`, set `fingerIsTouching` to YES and update `touchLocation` to the correct location.
In your SKScene's `-update:` method, check if `fingerIsTouching` is YES and move your character according to `touchLocation`. I recommend using `-update:` because it is called once per frame, which is exactly enough. You might have to use some other method for moving the character than `SKAction` though.

Don't forget to update `touchLocation` in `-touchesMoved:`, and reset `fingerIsTouching` inside `-touchesCancelled:` and `-touchesEnded:` :)

Sorry for the Obj-C, hope this illustrates the point.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, although a bit more work then I was wanting, it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can register a long touch event like this:

```
let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I thought this would work as well, however I'm running into the same problem as before. The action function called by the gesture is only called once every time the finger is moved. Since I'm centering the node, and moving it, to the position of the touch, the touches current position changes. So because of this the node will stop following the finger because it thinks it's reached the fingers position, when in reality the fingers position has just changed due to the movement from the node.

Comment: A good idea of what I'm looking for is how movement works in Apples SpriteKit example adventure game. I was going to take a look at that later tonight.

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 4:**

You'll first want to make **GameScene** a *UIGestureRecognizerDelegate*:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

And so you'll also need to add the delegate method to the **GameScene** class:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {        
        return true
}
```

Then inside **GameScene**'s `override func didMove(to view: SKView) {` add the following:

```
let pressed:UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(sender:)))
pressed.delegate = self
pressed.minimumPressDuration = 0.1
view.addGestureRecognizer(pressed)
```

Finally inside **GameScene** add your function to handle the long press (within which you can also discern the long press's state too):

```
func longPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

     if sender.state == .began { print("LongPress BEGAN detected") }            
     if sender.state == .ended { print("LongPress ENDED detected") }

}
```